# Bitcoind account negative balance

Tags: daemon, account, bitcoin, bitcoind

When using the accounts feature, an individual account balance may get negative if you spend more than its balance. That often happens, even if tou check the balance, due to transaction fees that are added to the transaction. Is there a way to configure bitcoin daemon to not allow an account to have a negative balance?

Answer (score 1):

I looked around, and it seems like bitcoind is supposed to do that. Here is a link to an issue that was presented on that. Feel free to read through it. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2079